# Is my understanding of how binoculars work mathematically accurate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

Let's say that I'm viewing a 10-meter-long object from 2 kilometers away using a pair of binoculars with 160x magnification.

[This](https://rechneronline.de/sehwinkel/angular-diameter.php) calculator states that, to the naked eye, a 10-meter object at 2 kilometers has an apparent size of 0.286 degrees.

From my admittedly not-entirely-watertight understanding of apparent size and arcs, the effect of the binoculars can be represented by the equation 0.286 * 160 = 45.76, meaning that that 10-meter object would instead have an apparent size of 45.76 degrees.

However, I feel like I'm missing something here. Am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [This](https://rechneronline.de/sehwinkel/angular-diameter.php) calculator states that, to the naked eye, a 10-meter object
> at 2 kilometers has an apparent size of 0.286 degrees.

[The calculator is mistaken](https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/product/binoculars/tips): the $0.286^\circ$ that it returns is the **actual field of view**, not the **apparent field of view**. (By elementary trigonometry, this angle is just $2\arctan\frac{10/2}{2000}.$)

> the effect of a pair of binoculars with 160x magnification can be
> represented by the equation 0.286 * 160 = 45.76, meaning that that
> 10-meter object would instead have an apparent size of 45.76 degrees.

Your equation is incorrect: $$\text{apparent field of view}\neq\text{magnification $\times$ actual field of view}.$$ Instead, by elementary right-angled trigonometry, $$\text{magnification}\\=\frac{\text{actual distance}}{\text{apparent distance}}\\=\left(\frac{\text{object height}}2\div\tan\frac{\text{apparent field of view}}2\right)\\\div\left(\frac{\text{object height}}2\div\tan\frac{\text{actual field of view}}2\right),$$ so $$\text{apparent field of view}\\=2\arctan\left(\text{magnification}\times\tan\frac{\text{actual field of view}}2\right)\\=43.6^\circ.$$